# Loading data from text file into a dictionary

Tags: c#

I have a file consisting of a list of text which looks as follows:

```
ABC Abbey something
ABD Aasdasd
```

[This is the text file](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cba1875490330f772950)

The first string will always be the length of 3. So I want to loop through the file content, store those first 3 letters as Key and remaining as value. I am removing white space between them and Substringing as follows to store. The key works out fine but the line where I am storing the value returns following error. **ArgumentOutOfRangeException**

This is the exact code causing the problem.

```
line.Substring(4, line.Length)
```

If I call the subString between 0 and line.length it works fine. As long as I call it between 1and upwards - line.length I get the error. Honestly don't get it and been at it for hours. Some assistance please.

```
class Program {

        static string line;
        static Dictionary<string, string> stations = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var lines = File.ReadLines("C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\a.txt");
            foreach (var l in lines) {
                line = l.Replace("\t", "");
                stations.Add(line.Substring(0, 3), line.Substring(4, line.Length));//error caused by this line
            }

            foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> item in stations) {
                //Console.WriteLine(item.Key);
                Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: No need for the two argument version; `"ABC XYZ".Substring(4);` is `"XYZ" ` ...

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks that works though am still puzzled why it doesn't work with current code.

Comment: because you try to read beyond the end of the string

Comment: The second parameter is length, not end index.

Comment: @juharr Got it. I was indeed thinking it is end index. Thanks.

Comment: @Trevor_zam A lot of people make that mistake especially if they're used to Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the documentation specifies it will throw an [ArgumentOutOfRangeException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception(v=vs.110).aspx) if:

> `startIndex` plus `length` indicates a position not within this instance.

With the signature:

```
public string Substring(int startIndex, int length)
```

Since you use `line.Length`, you know that `startIndex` plus `length` will be `4+line.Length` which is definitely not a position of this instance.

I recommend using the [one parameter version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public string Substring(int startIndex)
```

Thus `line.Substring(3)` (credit to @adv12 for [spotting that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34727535/loading-data-from-text-file-into-a-dictionary/34727629#comment57201218_34727629)). Since here you only should provide the `startIndex`. Of course you can use `line.SubString(3,line.Length-3)`, but as always, better use a library since libraries are made to make programs fool-proof (this is not intended as offensive, simply make sure you reduce the amount of brain cycles for this task). Mind however that it still can throw an error if:

> `startIndex` is less than zero or greater than the length of this instance.

So better provide checks that `3` is less than or equal to `line.length`...

## Additional advice

Perhaps you should take a look to *regex capturing*. Now each key in your file contains three characters. But it is possible that in the (near) future four characters will be possible. Using regex capture, you could specify a pattern such that it is less likely that errors will occur during parsing.

Comment: Note, additionally, that he is performing the substring on a line that has already had the tabs removed, so he really wants to start the substring at index 3 rather than index 4.

Comment: @adv12: indeed. Although I think extracting using a split or regex capture will be less error prone in general.

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually get less than the length of total line:

```
line.Substring(4, line.Length - 4)    //subtract the chars which you're skipping
```

Your string:

```
ABC Abbey something
Length = 19
Start  = 4
Remaining chars = 19 - 4 = 15 //and you are expecting 19, that is the error
```

Comment: Note, additionally, that he is performing the substring on a line that has already had the tabs removed, so he really wants to start the substring at index 3 rather than index 4.

Comment: It will not cause the error, because OP is using `string.Length` property., not specifying a fixed length.

Comment: Well if the file contains an error, for instance a line with only three characters, it could result in the program crashing whereas simply ignoring the line will probably be a more reasonable solution.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that starting at 4 will cause an exception; I'm saying that starting at 4 will get him the wrong data.

Comment: @Shaharyar  +1. Been going about thinking 2nd parameter is end index.

Comment: @adv12 Good catch. Have changed it.

Comment: Both of you are right, as OP is reading a text file there could be a lot of possible validations.

Comment: @Trevor_zam You should consider what **adv12** and **Willem Van Onsem** have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late answer that doesn't address what's wrong with your code but I feel that has already been done by other people. Instead I have different way to make the dictionary that doesn't involve substring at all so it's a little more robust, IMHO.

As long as you can guarantee that the two values are always separated by tab then this would work even if there were more or less characters in the key. It uses LINQ which should be fine from .NET 3.5.

```
// LINQ
using System.Linq;

// Creates a string[][] array with the list of keys in the first array position
// and the values in the second
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"path/to/file.txt")
                .Select(s => s.Split('\t'))
                .ToArray();

// Your dictionary
Dictionary<string, string> stations = new Dictionary<string, string>();

// Loop through the array and add the key/value pairs to the dictionary
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    // For example lines[i][0] = ABW, lines[i][1] = Abbey Wood
    stations[lines[i][0]] = lines[i][1];
}

// Prove it works
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in stations)
{
    MessageBox.Show(entry.Key + " - " + entry.Value);
}
```

Hope this makes sense and gives you an alternate to consider ;-)